# Is it okay to interrupt Memtest86+?

Tags: memtest86+, memtest

My Wasta Linux machine has been freezing at seemingly random moments. (Not slowing down; only freezing to the point where it won't respond to any interrupts except a hard restart.)

I'm running Memtest86+ to help me diagnose the issue, and I expected it to take a while, but it's already been 13 hours with no end in sight. There's other work that I need to get done.

Is it okay to interrupt Memtest86+ while it's running without adversely affecting the machine?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You can press Esc to cause a reboot first, if that makes you feel better. But there's nothing wrong with yanking the plug while running Memtest86+. All it does is read/write from the RAM, which as you already know, is volatile once power is removed.

Comment: If the machine is freezing but without a kernel error (check kernel logs after reboot) then your disk may be failing.

Comment: I had a similar issue (freezing to the point where it won't respond to any interrupts except a hard restart) except in my case a reboot didn't always help. I reseated the RAM and I haven't had problems since.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you're talking about `memtest86`/`memtest86+`, as in the bootable programs, sure. Interrupting it won't do anything, since it never writes any persistent data. In fact, the tests are intentionally endless - it'll just keep running passes until you stop it.

---

memtest is structured as a number of *tests*, each of a specific pattern. A single completed run through all selected tests is known as a *pass*. As mentioned before, you can safely abort at any time, simply by switching off the machine.

There is no optimal number of passes - an obvious failure will be caught in the first pass, while intermittent failures might take a hundred passes to appear (at which point you might as well get ECC RAM). I used to recommend running at least 10 passes to catch the more common intermittent failures, though with larger RAM capacities these days it could take too long.

Comment: Is an intermittent failure more likely to show up in 10 consecutive passes or could I also run 1 pass per day over a period of 10 days and use the machine for other stuff in between passes?

Comment: Running 10 consecutive passes is better, since an continuous and lengthy memtest86 run can pick up errors caused by overheating. Other than that, I believe that once a complete pass is completed all the consecutive passes are identical.

Comment: I tend to run it for "as long as possible" which is at least overnight, maybe a weekend.  "number of passes" doesn't really come into it.

Comment: ECC memory: Fallen out of favor.